# References missing from c# Class Library created in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, class, reference, .net-assembly

I've got a class library. I had created it with VS 2013 a few years ago. It has a `References` section where I can right click and `Add Reference`.

I just created a new c# class library in VS 2019 and `References` does not exist. It does have a `Dependencies subgroup`.

This seems like a newbie question but I can't find any suggestions of how to add `Assembly References` and can't think of what I'm missing.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: right click the project and add -> project reference

Comment: I tried that, but there is was no option to choose Assemblies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just figured it out. I had created a .NET Standard Library vs. .NET Framework. I just created a new project, chose .NET Framework class library and now I see Reference.

Answer (score 1):

If you right click on "Dependencies", there should be an option "Add Reference" - this will open the "References" window and you should be able to add packages, projects or .Net assemblies to the solution. They are then listed under "Dependencies".

Comment: That's the problem, I didn't see it just Add Reference. I did see that I had Add Project Reference. But I just figured it out and posted as the answer.